# Issue with maps url opening with webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using WebView to open maps url (which I get with Google maps share with dialog).

```
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
val webSettings: WebSettings = webView.settings
webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
val url = "https://maps.app.goo.gl/ei5DupR88SYBF8Am8"
webView.loadUrl(url)
```

But url is not opened like any other url.

It looks like, "https://" is replaced with "intent://" and WebView cannot open invalid url.

Any idea why that happens and how to avoid it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by overriding "shouldOverrideUrlLoading":

```
companion object {
    const val FALLBACK_URL = "browser_fallback_url="
}


webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest):
            Boolean {

        val url = request.url
        val urlString = url.toString()
        val fallbackUrl = urlString.subSequence(
                urlString.indexOf(FALLBACK_URL) + FALLBACK_URL.length,
                urlString.length)
                .toString()
        webView.loadUrl(URLDecoder.decode(fallbackUrl, "UTF-8"))
        return true
    }
}
```